# Tesseract ambiguity files work different for editing

Tags: tesseract, ambiguity, training-data, unichar

I want to edit some text like Female and Male because When I test them I found them as FemaIe and MaIe (I mean with Capital I not small L (l) ). And I want to solve this issue using ambfile like;

v1

6_tab_F_e_m_a_I_e_tab_6_tab_F_e_m_a_l_e_tab_1

4_tab_M_a_I_e_tab_4_tab_M_a_l_e_tab_1

But When I retest my results , they were worse. I found the Female as F and Male as M.
What I am doing wrong ? To use amb file like that is a wrong idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fields should be tab separated, according to [Tesseract Training Wiki](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract#the-last-file-unicharambigs).

Comment: Yes.. I couldnt type well here but I followed the instruction in wiki (I tried to edit more understanble I hope). There is no problem about it. And I made another test I can use ambiguty ; except this issue.